# Jquery delay is inconsistent while using inside a setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, fadein

I want to fade in different elements of a page **one by one** with jQuery fadeIn function. It's working but the delay between two fadeIn are not consistent. Randomly some elements appear sooner than the others. What am I doing wrong? I am using the following code to achieve that.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.showTime .appr').each(function(index){
        $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(400);
    });
}, 50);
```

**Note:** The setInterval function is used because I am waiting for the class 'showTime' to be added to the body tag, by some other function.

Comment: Calling this code over and over every 50 milliseconds is a bad idea.  At the very least clear the interval once you've found the class you're waiting for.

Comment: You shouldn't use `setInterval` to "wait" for something. Better explicitly get a callback for when that something is ready. At least, stop the interval once you've found the something!

Comment: Yes I know this is not an elegant way to do this but I cannot use a callback as the function invoking the 'showtime' class is written somewhere else and I am not allowed to edit that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) you are causing this code to be called every 50ms, even after the `.showTime` class has been added which is causing the strange behavior you are seeing. If you assign the result of `setInterval()` to a variable you can then use [`clearInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) on it once the class has been added, and your selector returns DOM elements:

```
// track the interval so we can clear it
var myInterval;
myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    // try to match elements with the selector
    var elements = $('.showTime .appr');
    // if the length is non-zero...
    if ( elements.length ){
        // clear the interval
        clearInterval(myInterval);
        // run your code
        $('.showTime .appr').each(function(index){
            $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
}, 50);
```

All that said, this is probably not the best design pattern - it would be better to use a callback rather than polling and eating up CPU.

Comment: I think the idea is for the `setInterval` to be sort of a "polling" checking every 50 ms for the class to be added.  This would not accomplish that.

Comment: @JamesMontagne good point, didn't catch that in the question. still the cause of the issue though, but i'll update it

Comment: You saved me from a lot of trouble! Works like a charm! I logged and checked it runs not more than just 6-7 times! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, since this worked for you word you mind marking it as the answer? Thanks!